# PHP array writing error

Tags: php

I'm trying to write an extremely simple php voting system for a website. Basically, votes are tallied in a text file that has 3 lines. Each line is simply a number. A vote file without any votes would look like:

```
0
0
0
```

Here's the php I'm using:

```
$file = "votes.txt";
$votes = file($file); 
$votes[0] = intval($votes[0]) + 1;
$voteWrite = strval($votes[0]) . "\n" . strval($votes[1]) . "\n" . strval($votes[2]);
file_put_contents($file, $voteWrite);
```

So the array holds each line of the text file, and if this is the code for voting for the first option, the value of that line is incremented by one, then the whole array is written back to the file after being concatenated into one string, preserving the lines of the array. Ideally the text file would now read:

```
1
0
0
```

But instead it reads:

```
10
0
```

Can someone please tell me why this is? php really doesn't want to work with me...
Thanks.

**Edit:**

I really don't understand this file() stuff...here's a test I set up:

```
$file = "votes.txt";
$votes = file($file); 
$option1 = $votes[0];
$option2 = $votes[1];
$option3 = $votes[2];
```

Followed by, in JavaScript:

```
alert(<?php echo $option1; ?>);
alert(<?php echo $option2; ?>);
alert(<?php echo $option3; ?>);
```

With the text file reading 28, 3, and 49 on 3 separate lines. The alerts return, "28", "450", and "undefined". What the hell?

Comment: Why are you not using a database?

Comment: What does a `var_dump($votes)` right after your `file()` command show? Does your file even get read properly? Plus, you've got a fundamental race condition there, and WILL lose votes at some point.

Comment: The site is being hosted through a university server, and working with the university to get a database hosted on the site is a nightmare.

Comment: Using serialize/unserialize (or even json_encode/json_decode) instead of line positioning might be more intuitive for the data storage

Comment: @MarcB What would you recommend for dealing with the race condition, assuming that the OP can't get any kind of database service? Would writing each individual vote to a file using append be safer?

Comment: @octem: flock() or other locking methods. if you can't use a db, at least prevent other parallel scripts from being able to snipe the file's contents out from one another.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
// Define the whole path of where the file is
$fileName = '/var/home/votes/votes.txt';

// Check if the file exists - if not create it
if (!file_exists($fileName))
{
    $data = array('0', '0', '0');
    $line = implode("\n", $data);
    file_put_contents($line, $fileName);
}

// The file exists so read it
$votes = file($fileName);

// What happens if the file does not return 3 lines?
$vote_one   = isset($votes[0]) ? intval($votes[0]) : 0;
$vote_two   = isset($votes[1]) ? intval($votes[1]) : 0;
$vote_three = isset($votes[2]) ? intval($votes[2]) : 0;

$vote_one++;

$line = "{$vote_one}\n{$vote_two}\n{$vote_three}";
file_put_contents($line, $fileName);
```

I didn't do much other than remove the str_val and put some error checking. Try it out, it might work better.

It might be a lot better if you chose a different storing method than this. Changing slightly the format will provide a lot more flexibility for the future but this decision lies with you and it depends on what your constraints are.

Using something like [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), will allow you to store even structured data in your file and retrieve it as it was before and it is UTF8 safe.

So should you choose to go with that route, your code becomes:

```
// Define the whole path of where the file is
$fileName = '/var/home/votes/votes.txt';

// Check if the file exists - if not create it
if (!file_exists($fileName))
{
    $data = array('0', '0', '0');
    $line = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents($line, $fileName);
}

// The file exists so read it
$line = file_get_contents($fileName);
$data = json_decode($line, TRUE);

$data[0] = intval($data[0]) + 1;

$line = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents($line, $fileName);
```

json_decode needs the TRUE as the second parameter so as to create an associative array when decoding the data.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't store the info as a serialized array? If not, you might want to consider this solution:

```
$file = "votes.txt";
$votes = file_get_contents($file); 
$votes = $votes ? unserialize($votes) : array(0,0,0);

$votes[0] += 1;

file_put_contents($file, serialize($votes));
```

If you're reusing this file in other language or for some other purpose, I think the JSON suggestion is a good one, or even simply storing the values with comma delimitations like a CSV.

**As for why your example isn't working**: I'm not entirely sure. Zeros and line-ending interpretations can be quirky sometimes. I wonder if the zero values are throwing PHP off somewhere, possibly interpreting a line as empty? You might want to try a starting `votes.txt` file that looks like:

```
1     
1
1
```

See if it's still behaving that way.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the weird number thing was a result of not using intval() around the array values, and using @file_put_contents instead of file_put_contents...however I won't be able to go down this road, I didn't think far enough ahead and PHP won't be able to address my needs.